# How to extrude and leave the original in place?

Tags: modeling, mesh, extrude

How can I extrude a part of a surface, while leaving that part in place? That would mean the extrude function makes a copy.

For example, when I subdivide a face of a cube in 9 squares and extrude (<kbd>E</kbd>) the middle square, I get a little cube on top of the initial cube. However, when I hide the top face of the little cube it's clear that the little cube has no bottom. How can I extrude while leaving the bottom in place?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most practical procedure on ANY mesh would perhaps be *select the Face*, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (duplicate), cancel (<kbd>Esc</kbd>), extrude (<kbd>E</kbd>)

Comment: Are all vertices connected?

Comment: who would have thought that such a hack would solve hours of work! I suggest deduplicating (merginge by distance) afterwards. And maybe reversing some normals.

Comment: Still works with Blender 2.83! @atomicbezierslinger Yes and no. It does create new edges and faces on the outside that connect the two "layers" but the inside vertices of the original layer aren't connected to any of the inside vertices of the new layer.

Comment: where does this secret shift d duplicate command in the user interface exist

Comment: How is possible that Balender does not have such a feature? I remember sketch-up ctrl modifier key that worked great....

Answer (score 6):

You may use ***Edges Only*** option. With the *Edge select* enabled select the region you want to extrude, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>-->*Edges Only*. You may then fill the gap with the <kbd>F</kbd> key.
[image]

You may also just press <kbd>E</kbd> after you select the edges. After extruding the selected portion you may press <kbd>Space</kbd> and type ***Grid Fill*** to automatically fill the gap with mesh.
[image]

Comment: Reality unfortunately is not so simple. The surface I want to "extrude with bottom remaining" is a complex mesh, so it can't be recreated with "Fill" or even "Grid Fill" ...

Comment: @TavernSenses it would help if you edit your question and show what specific "complex mesh" you are talking about!

Comment: You can probably think yourself of a thousand meshes that can't be recreated with "Fill" or "Grid Fill", so what kind of mesh it is exactly does not matter for the argument.

Answer (score 5):

Duplicate and Bridge Edge Loops

- Select the Vertices you want.
- [Shift D] Duplicate Move along some axis.

[image]

Result of Duplicate Move above with color for ease of viewing.

- Select boundary of source and select boundary of destination.  Vertex Groups may help you remember your selection.  Menu Select Boundary Loop may assist.
- Bridge Edge Loops
- When you look closely you can see the hidden surfaces has identical faces as the duplicated surface

[image]

Image below is the original selected vertices that were duplicated.

[image]