# Why is extrude just moving face instead of expanding it?

Tags: modeling, extrude

I have a model like this, planes, surrounded by cubes/
[image: modelbottom]
[image: modeltop]

I want to extrude all the faces up to give it a little extra thickness before exporting to Zbrush like this

[image: model extruded]

but when I make the extrusion, when I flip it back over, all of the faces on the top have just been moved, not extruded, which is not what I want. The cubes all extrude down, but the planes do not.

[image: bad end result]

Any idea why it is doing this? Any idea how I can make it not do that?

Answer (score 5):

I found this answer to a related post [How to extrude and leave the original in place?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43505/how-to-extrude-and-leave-the-original-in-place)

Select the Face, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (duplicate), cancel (<kbd>Esc</kbd>), extrude (<kbd>E</kbd>)
then select everything and do a [Merge by Distance](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.81/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html#merge-by-distance) in order to remove the duplicated verts.